# Limiting Characters or Lines - Asp MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to asp mvc and I'm currently trying to limit the text on an item in my site, how can i limit the text for:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Text)
```

I have tried just creating another item in the model like this:

```
public string Text {get; set; }

private string _limitText;

[StringLength(30)]
public string limitText
{
   get
   {
       return (_limitText = this.Text)
   }
   set
   {
       _limitedText = Text;
   }
}
```

However i get errors when updating database with the Nuget Console:
"String or binary data would be truncated. the statement has been terminated"

All help appreciated.

Comment: That probably means you already have data that is too long in the DB

Comment: @SLaks Yes i do, but i want to limit the data that is in the database

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Can you post the code in which you try to update the record and get the error message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using EF code first and trying to upgrade your DB using code first migrations.

Since you have already created table with `VARCHAR(MAX)` length (If you do not specify length on your property it will be considered as max length by EF), you will need to first delete all records from DB which has length more then 30 for `limittext` column. Else you wont be able to upgrade your version using code first migration.

If you do not want to loose your data then clone your table and then migrate your database and then copy your data back to original table.

You can clone table using following query

```
SELECT * 
INTO CustomerClone
FROM Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Your chief problem here is that your new property, `limitText` has both a getter and setter and you're filling it with the full text from `Text`. If a property has a getter and setter, then Entity Framework persists it to the database. That alone is probably not ideal, since you're basically duplicating data, but let's say you wanted it to actually be persisted. It's value is set to the full string of `Text`, but it's going to then be persisted into a column that has a maxlength of 30 characters, hence the error. There's many ways to fix this problem. First, you can simply set the value to just the truncated string:

```
_limitText = this.Text.Substring(0, 30);
```

Then, it will save fine because the value will always be 30 characters of less. However, more likely than not, you simply shouldn't persist this field. That can be accomplished by either 1) removing the setter or 2) decorating the property with `[NotMapped]`.

Also, you could simply not use this extra property at all. There's no need to use `Html.DisplayFor` here, so you could simply just do the following in your view instead:

```
@Model.Text.Substring(0, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are simple 2 ways how the issue can be solved:

First, you can use attribute [`maxlength`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) to specify maximum length of the text that can be input. In this case you need to change `DisplayFor` to `TextBoxFor` and use `maxlength` attribute:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Text, new { maxlength=30 } )
```

Second, you can take first 30 symbols of the property by using `Substring` function. This is not very nice approach but it works.